# Удаленное управление реестром ПК

Tags: windows, delphi, реестр

Какая функция (процедура) в delphi отвечает за удаленное управление реестром ПК в сети? Буду рад любому ответу. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Собственно, всегда доступна функция API [`RegConnectRegistry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724840) и соответствующий метод класса-обертки — [`TRegistry`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry)`.`[`RegistryConnect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.RegistryConnect).

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как вариант, можно создать программу-клиент, которая будет получать команды от сервера( в вашем случае программы-сервера ) и выполнять их на компьютере. Программа-клиент должна быть установлена на компьютерах, реестром которых вы планируете управлять, ну а сервер - один, на вашем компьютере. Кстати лучше в этом случае использовать управление по интернету, нежели по протоколу TCP/IP.

Comment: А чем не нравится программа-клиент от microsoft (Remote Registry service)? Тем, что она от microsoft?

И что есть "управление по интернету", и чем оно отличается от управления "по протоколу TCP/IP"?

Comment: Много чем отличается. Протокол TCP/IP чаще используется в локальных и корпоративных сетях, тем более, чтобы осуществлять управление по этому протоколу, надо иметь "белый" IP.

Comment: Извините, я не в курсе цветовой дифференциации ip-адресов. "Белый", очевидно -- полученный официально, и признаваемый даже злыми маршрутизаторами. Но всё равно ответ сильно непонятен. Тем более, что протокол TCP/IP лежит в основе интернета.

Comment: @Asen, просвятите отстающих, как предавать данные в интернете, не используя TCP/IP ? 

Возможно Вы просто очень строго относитесь к терминологии, но я подозреваю, что большинство, говоря TCP/IP, подразумевают также ICMP и UDP.

Comment: @avp Строгость терминологии тут ни причём. "Стек протоколов TCP/IP" -- словосочетание устоявшееся до официальности. Туда, кроме ICMP и UDP входит ещё много чего.

Comment: Лучше ехать на поезде, чем по железной дороге :-)